# File is not readable when script is called by cron

Tags: cron, email, mime-types

This really has me scratching my head. I have a PERL script on a RHEL 7 server that creates an xlsx file via MIME::Lite and emails it to several people. If I run the script from the command line it works fine. If cron calls the script, it returns "/software/YAVALN/yln/holds_not_being_pulled.xlsx: not readable" when it tries to attach the file to the email. Cron and the script have the same user. Permissions on the file are 644. What would cause this?

**Update**: Here's the section of code that as best as I can tell is failing. Note that the "or dies" are not being triggered so I don't exactly know where the "not readable" message gets returned. In the section just before this, it writes the Excel file and I can tell that is successfully happening because the date/time is updated (and if I delete the file and run the script again, it creates a working Excel file).

I just added the unlink line. It neither throws an error nor deletes the file. I even tried setting permissions to 777. I also tried setting the full path instead of just the local file name. Nothing works.

I have scripts in another directory which use the same PERL module and work fine. I've compared ownership and permissions for both the scripts and the directories.

```perl
    if (length($offenders) > 0) {
      my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        From => 'user@domain.com',
        "Reply-To" => 'user@domain.com',
        To => 'user@domain.com',
        Subject => 'Libraries not pulling holds',
        Type => 'multipart/mixed',
      );
    
      $msg->attach(
        Type => 'TEXT',
        Data => "These libraries have not pulled holds for a minimum of $bizdayslimit business days. \n\nLibraries represented: $offenders",
      ) or die "Text attach failed: $!\n";
    
      $msg->attach(
        Type         => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        Path            => 'holds_not_being_pulled.xlsx',
        Filename        => 'holds_not_being_pulled.xlsx',
        Disposition  => 'attachment'
      ) or die "Excel file attach failed: $!\n";
      $msg->send or die "Send failed: $!\n";
      unlink('holds_not_being_pulled.xlsx') or die "Can't delete file: $!";
    }
```

Comment: What exact command tries to read the file -- is it the part that attempts to send the file by email?  It may help if you included the script (or a Minimum Working Example) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ashamedly, the problem was a combination of not including full paths (even though it didn't seem like I needed them) and using double quotes instead of single quotes.